# Complicated dataframe transformation with moving multiple columns into one

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
 Date      Mean_sum  Current_value  Working_perc  Type1   Type2
2020-08-04   124          142          15%         1        A
2020-08-04   117          109          24%         1        B
2020-08-04   98           105          21%         1        C
2020-08-04   114          127          11%         2        A
2020-08-04   145          139          22%         2        B
2020-08-04   115          125          55%         2        C
2020-08-05   121          125          12%         1        A
2020-08-05   111          122          24%         1        B
2020-08-05   105          108          21%         1        C
2020-08-05   119          122          11%         2        A
2020-08-05   148          149          22%         2        B
2020-08-05   118          127          55%         2        C
```

I want to stretch Date column to 4 hours from 00:00:00 to 04:00:00, with keeping same values for each hour. And I want to unite columns  Mean_sum, Current_value and Working_perc into one column: Metrics. So, desired result must look like this:

```
Date               Date_hours           Metrics        Value   Type1   Type2
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 00:00:00      Mean_sum        124      1       A
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 01:00:00      Mean_sum        124      1       A
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 02:00:00      Mean_sum        124      1       A
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 03:00:00      Mean_sum        124      1       A
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 04:00:00      Mean_sum        124      1       A
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 00:00:00    Current_value     142      1       B
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 01:00:00    Current_value     142      1       B
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 02:00:00    Current_value     142      1       B
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 03:00:00    Current_value     142      1       B
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 04:00:00    Current_value     142      1       B
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 00:00:00    Working_perc      15%      1       C
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 01:00:00    Working_perc      15%      1       C
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 02:00:00    Working_perc      15%      1       C
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 03:00:00    Working_perc      15%      1       C
2020-08-04     2020-08-04 04:00:00    Working_perc      15%      1       C
.............................................................................
```

How could i do that? I have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically same answer as @thelatemail but using `tidyverse` functions.

Get data in long format, add rows, add hours to each date-time.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(across(c(Mean_sum, Current_value,Working_perc), as.character), 
         Date = as.POSIXct(Date)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(Mean_sum, Current_value,Working_perc)) %>%
  uncount(5) %>%
  mutate(Date = Date + lubridate::hours(0:4))

# A tibble: 180 x 5
#   Date                Type1 Type2 name          value
#   <dttm>              <int> <chr> <chr>         <chr>
# 1 2020-08-04 00:00:00     1 A     Mean_sum      124  
# 2 2020-08-04 01:00:00     1 A     Mean_sum      124  
# 3 2020-08-04 02:00:00     1 A     Mean_sum      124  
# 4 2020-08-04 03:00:00     1 A     Mean_sum      124  
# 5 2020-08-04 04:00:00     1 A     Mean_sum      124  
# 6 2020-08-04 00:00:00     1 A     Current_value 142  
# 7 2020-08-04 01:00:00     1 A     Current_value 142  
# 8 2020-08-04 02:00:00     1 A     Current_value 142  
# 9 2020-08-04 03:00:00     1 A     Current_value 142  
#10 2020-08-04 04:00:00     1 A     Current_value 142  
# … with 170 more rows
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Date = c("2020-08-04", "2020-08-04", "2020-08-04", 
"2020-08-04", "2020-08-04", "2020-08-04", "2020-08-05", "2020-08-05", 
"2020-08-05", "2020-08-05", "2020-08-05", "2020-08-05"), Mean_sum = c(124L, 
117L, 98L, 114L, 145L, 115L, 121L, 111L, 105L, 119L, 148L, 118L
), Current_value = c(142L, 109L, 105L, 127L, 139L, 125L, 125L, 
122L, 108L, 122L, 149L, 127L), Working_perc = c("15%", "24%", 
"21%", "11%", "22%", "55%", "12%", "24%", "21%", "11%", "22%", 
"55%"), Type1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), Type2 = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", 
"B", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: I got this error: Error: Failed to create output due to bad names. * Choose another strategy with `names_repair`

Comment: Probably you already have column named `name` , replace `pivot_longer` line with `pivot_longer(cols = c(Mean_sum, Current_value,Working_perc), names_to = 'col')`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a reshape wide-to-long, followed by repeating each row. There's about 4 million methods for the first part, so here's a base R version:

```
## reshape to long format
idv <- match(c("Type1","Type2","Date"), names(dat))
out <- reshape(dat, idvar=idv, varying=list(-idv), direction="long",
               v.names="Value", timevar="Metrics", times=names(dat)[-idv])

## repeat each row 5 times and add 0:4 hours in turn to each set of 5 rows
out <- out[rep(seq_len(nrow(out)), each=5),]
out$Date <- as.POSIXct(out$Date, tz="UTC") + as.difftime(0:4, units="hours")
rownames(out) <- NULL

## check a few rows at the start and end
rbind(head(out), tail(out))
#                   Date Type1 Type2      Metrics Value
#1   2020-08-04 00:00:00     1     A     Mean_sum   124
#2   2020-08-04 01:00:00     1     A     Mean_sum   124
#3   2020-08-04 02:00:00     1     A     Mean_sum   124
#4   2020-08-04 03:00:00     1     A     Mean_sum   124
#5   2020-08-04 04:00:00     1     A     Mean_sum   124
#6   2020-08-04 00:00:00     1     B     Mean_sum   117
#175 2020-08-05 04:00:00     2     B Working_perc   22%
#176 2020-08-05 00:00:00     2     C Working_perc   55%
#177 2020-08-05 01:00:00     2     C Working_perc   55%
#178 2020-08-05 02:00:00     2     C Working_perc   55%
#179 2020-08-05 03:00:00     2     C Working_perc   55%
#180 2020-08-05 04:00:00     2     C Working_perc   55%
```

The data I used was:

```
dat <- read.table(text=" Date      Mean_sum  Current_value  Working_perc  Type1   Type2
2020-08-04   124          142          15%         1        A
2020-08-04   117          109          24%         1        B
2020-08-04   98           105          21%         1        C
2020-08-04   114          127          11%         2        A
2020-08-04   145          139          22%         2        B
2020-08-04   115          125          55%         2        C
2020-08-05   121          125          12%         1        A
2020-08-05   111          122          24%         1        B
2020-08-05   105          108          21%         1        C
2020-08-05   119          122          11%         2        A
2020-08-05   148          149          22%         2        B
2020-08-05   118          127          55%         2        C", header=TRUE)
```

Comment: I get this: Error in names(data)[ix] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts. What does that means?